# Sections indexed with numbers subsections indexed with both numbers and letters

Tags: sectioning, numbering

Is it possible to set the environment in such a way that sections are indexed with numbers, and subsections with both numbers and letters? For example,

1 First section

1.1 First subsection

1.2 Second subsection

1.A first letter subsection

1.B second letter subsection

...

Comment: And what about the next subsection? Are there, in the same section, some subsections with numbers followed by some with letters? Or are they intermixed?

Comment: I think that's pretty easy to do with Denis's answer cause you can just use \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\Alph{subsection}} replace \Alph and \arabic as you see fit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. Quick and dirty, try:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}
\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\Alph{subsection}}
\subsection{Second subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course at some point you might have to go back to the original "indexing" scheme, perhaps for a subsections within a later section.

Comment: @PeterWilson Sure. This why I said it was quick and dirty